# How can I create a route like: /{project}/{module_name}/{sub-section}/{id}

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to create a route so it looks like this:

```
 /{project}/{module_type}/{module_name}/{sub-section}/{id}
```

So in terms of controller/action/id mapping it would be:

```
controller = module_type
action = sub-section
id = id
```

And there would be 2 other variables:

`project` and `module_name` that I would need.

What would my route look like:

I am using the latest version of MVC (MVC3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what your intentions are, but try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "NewOne", // Route name
    "{project}/{controller}/{module_name}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new
    {
        controller = "Default",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional,
        project = UrlParameter.Optional,
        module_name = UrlParameter.Optional
    } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Then by typing something like:

```
http://localhost:12345/Projekt3/Home/ModuleName/Index/2
```

Will get you to `HomeController` and `Index` action.

**Edit:**
I have added new action into HomeController:

```
public string Echo(string project, string module_name, int id)
{
    return project + " " + module_name + " " + id;
}
```

And then requested url:

```
http://localhost:25608/Projekt3/Home/ModuleName/Echo/2
```

The result is empty page with text:

```
Projekt3 ModuleName 2
```